# How do I set default SMB credentials at the user scope?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, smb

At work, we use Vagrant on Windows 10 with the Hyper-V provider and, necessarily, SMB synced folders. It gets kind of annoying typing our entire corporate domain username and password every time we `up` a box... is there any way to set default SMB credentials?

It needs to work with `Vagrantfile`s checked into source control and cloned onto any developer machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant loads multiple Vagrantfiles from different locations. One of those being a user Vagrantfile.

```
~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile
```

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/#load-order-and-merging

But, the only username and _password like options, as of Vagrant 2.2.7, are provided *directly* on the `synced_folder` method.

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/smb.html#options

Something you can do in the meantime is pull defualt username and domain info from environment vars...

**Vagrantfile**

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

default_smb_username = ENV['USERNAME']
default_smb_username = "#{ENV['USERNAME']}@#{ENV['USERDNSDOMAIN'].downcase}" if ENV['USERDNSDOMAIN']

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", smb_username: default_smb_username if default_smb_username
end
```

An issue has been opened asking for a solution.

https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11413